# Поиск в TextBox по выделенному фрагменту - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Помогите исправить код, нужно в Textbox 2 вывести не просто выделенный фрагмент textBox1, а полностью слово в которое он входит , если их несколько то выводить все

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string[] a = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\filt.txt", Encoding.Default);
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;
            String filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
            textBox1.Text = fileText;
            //MessageBox.Show("Файл открыт");
            string[] files = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            string path = Path.GetTempFileName();
            int size = files.Length;
            long s = 0;
            int i = 0;
            if (size > 1)
            {
                while (i < size)
                {
                    s = new FileInfo(files[i]).Length + s;
                    i++;
                }

            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox1.SelectionLength <= 0)
                MessageBox.Show("текст не выбран");
            if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
            {
                var text = textBox1.SelectedText;
                textBox2.Text = text;
               // if (textBox3.Contains(textBox1))
                 //   textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;



            }
}
```

Comment: зачем здесь код `button1_Click`?

Comment: я делаю в windowsforms, на кнопку делается поиск

Comment: у `TextBox` есть в т.ч. [свойства SelectionStart, SelectionLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) позиции (номер символа строки) начала и длины выделения в тексте; начало/конец слова ограничено пробелами(знаками пунктуации, др. символами-разделителями), найти первое появление которых относительно выделенного участка можно с помощью [String.LastIndexOfAny(Char[],Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5kbkt4sh(v=vs.110).aspx) , [String.IndexOfAny(Char[],Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/56y4ddbk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: но мне нужно не первое совпадение, а все вывести. У меня в переменной лежит значение выделенной части, как я поняла надо написать цикл в котором будет проверяться все слова на совпадение с этой переменной.